# no exporta mas de 16000 registros por excel

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Estoy creado un objeto de Excel

```
varApuExcObj_g := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
varApuLibLec_g := varApuExcObj_g.Workbooks.Open(chrNombArch__p);
varApuHojLec_g := varApuLibLec_g.Worksheets[1];
intLCID______g := LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT;
 ovaTemplate__g  := xlWBATWorksheet;
 wboExcePrinc_ := TExcelWorkbook.Create(Nil);
 wshExcePrinc_ := TExcelWorksheet.Create(Nil);
  excPrincipal.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
  excPrincipal.Connect;
  wboExcePrinc_.ConnectTo(excPrincipal.Workbooks.Add(ovaTemplate__g, intLCID______g));
  wshExcePrinc_.ConnectTo(excPrincipal.Worksheets[1] as _Worksheet);

  if chrNombHoja__g = '' then
  begin
    chrNombHoja__g := 'Hoja';
  end;
  intContHoja__g := 1;
  wshExcePrinc_.Name := chrNombHoja__g+inttostr(intContHoja__g);
```

Exporta  todo bien, el problema es que cuando es un volumen amplio digamos de una tabla de 10 campos con 459000 registros no exporta todo los datos sino que se llega a 16000 filas cuando lo que en realidad debería quedar en el Excel son las 459000 filas correspondientes a los datos de la tabla; entonces mi pregunta es hay algún método para para que exporte toda la información.
.

Comment: Hay varias maneras de _exportar_ información a Excel, sugiero que pongas el código relevante de la exportación que estás haciendo a manera de ejemplo. Te invito a leer [ask] y como publicar un [mcve].

Comment: Deberías completar la información. Decir "no exporta más datos" no da mucha información del posible problema. Si hay error deberías explicar cual es y descreibirlo con detalle; Si no hay error, simplemente puede ser que la librería está programada así. Podrías aportar información relevente como la versión de Delphi,...